# Which of the following group is isomorphic to the group $S_3\times \mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

The group $S_3\times \mathbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to one of the following groups:

$\mathbb Z_{12}$,  $\mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2$,  $A_4$,   $D_6$…?

I know that $\mathbb Z_{12}$,  $\mathbb Z_6\times \mathbb Z_2$ will not be the answer. So, which one between $A_4$,   $D_6$…?

Comment: $A_4$ does not contain a subgroup of oder $6$.

Comment: Please, explain #mesel, how you say that...

Comment: $A_4$ has more than one subgroup oder of $3$. You may think $<(1,2,3)>$ and $<(2,3,4)>$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $6$. Then $H$ is normal in $A_4$. Then $H$ has a uniqe subgroup of order $3$. So, $A_4$ has a uniqe subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: I think the answer is D_6. Because, A_4 has 8 elements of order 3, but S_3xZ_2 has 2 elements of order 3. Is it correct..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$G=S_3\times\mathbb{Z_2}$$ is not abelian and not cyclic hence it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_6}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. Also the group $A_4$ doesn't have an element of order $6$ but $G$ has, say $\{(1,2,3),1\}$, so correct option is $D_6$

Comment: Can we construct an explicit isomorphism between the two groups?

Answer (score 1):

$D_6$ contains normal subgroups $G, H$ such that $G \cong S_3$ and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Since $G \cap H=\{1\}$ you can conclude $D_6 \cong G \times H$. I don't know if this helps, depends on your mathematical background.

Comment: Yes. If D_6 is inner direct product of such G and H, its clear to me. How I know about the existence of such G and H for the group D_6?

Comment: Write $D_6=\langle r, s \mid ord(r) = 6, ord(s) = 2, srs = r^{-1} \rangle$ (see Wikipedia for the definition of $D_n$). Then let $G:=\langle r^2, s \rangle$ and $H:=\langle r^3 \rangle$. Do you see that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic to $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$?